# Обращение к нескольким методам по цепочке

Tags: php, ооп

Сразу хочу извиниться за глупый вопрос)) Начал изучать ООП в php и наткнулся на такую запись `$this->MsLoader->MsHelper->addStyle('abc');`. Понимаю когда обращаются, например, так `$this->MsLoader();`. Первая запись означает что мы обращаемся ко всем методам подряд при этом возвращая значение и используя потом это значение в следующем методе или я совсем неправ?)

Comment: Объект в объекте в объекте в объекте, мы просто последовательно обращаемся к ним.

Comment: @DaemonHK, т.е. если записать так: `$this->MsLoader(); $this->MsHelper(); $this->addStyle('abc');` то это равносильно `$this->MsLoader->MsHelper->addStyle('abc');`?

Comment: нет, не равносильно, представьте что у вас есть объект Машина, у которого есть св-во/объект Дверь, у которого есть св-во/объект Стекло, у которого есть метод Опустить(). То есть вы говорите Машина->Дверь->Стекло->Опустить(), а обращаясь к ним по отдельности, Машина->Дверь, Машина->Дверь->Стекло вы получаете все их методы и св-ва. Как написали вы, так работать не будет, потому что нужно обращаться последовательно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется цепочкой вызовов. В если это методы одного и того же класса, то в каждом методе, который предполагает вызов дальнейших методов по цепочке, нужно возвращать объект этого класса, т.е. `$this`.

Возьмем, для примера, обычный класс:

```
Class Foo {
  public $bar;
  public $baz;

  public function setBar() {
    $this->bar = 'bar';    
  }
  public function setBaz() {
    $this->baz = 'baz';    
  }
}
```

Использовать его мы можем только таким образом:

```
$fooClass = new Foo();
$fooCLass->setBar();
$fooClass->setBaz();
```

Но если в каждом из этих сеттеров мы вернем `$this`, у нас получится следующее:

```
Class Foo {
  public $bar;
  public $baz;

  public function setBar() {
    $this->bar = 'bar';    
    return $this;
  }
  public function setBaz() {
    $this->baz = 'baz';    
    return $this;
  }
}
```

То можно будет сделать вот следующим образом:

```
$fooClass = (new Foo())->setBar()->setBaz();
```

Понятное дело, что возвращать объект этого же самого класса совсем не обязательно, и точно так же можно вернуть и другой объект - и по цепочке уже обратиться к его методу.

Answer (score 0):

В *PHP* чтение выражения со свойствами или методами классов происходит слева направо.

Давайте для примера вложим стандартный объект в стандартный объект:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->prop = new stdClass();
```

В объекте `object` есть объект `prop`.

Теперь вложим в `prop` экземпляр нового класса:

```
class abc {
    public function foo() {
        return 'some text';
    }
}
$object->prop->child = new abc();
```

После чего мы можем обратиться к методу `echo` так:

```
echo $object->prop->child->foo();
```

Это и есть ваш пример.

Comment: Вообще-то не совсем. У автора методы, а у вас свойства.

Comment: В случае методов вы можете декларировать класс в котором объявляете свойство являющееся объектом и присвоить этому свойству новый экземпляр уже другого класса. И так далее.
В итоге вызов будет выглядеть так: $this->one->two->three-> .. ->method()
Это довольно распространенная практика.

Comment: Это распространённая практика. **Но непонятно, какое отношение она имеет к вопросу, на который вы отвечали**

Comment: Это ответ для цепочки $this->MsLoader->MsHelper->addStyle('abc') заданный в вопросе.

В этом случае MsLoader является свойством типа объект. Но не методом.
Если мы рассмотрим случай с методами, возвращающими сам экземпляр класса, то обращение к ним выглядело бы так:  $this->MsLoader()->MsHelper()->addStyle('abc')

Это тоже синтаксически верно, но не соответствует вопросу.

$this->something - обращение к свойству, 
$this->something() - обращение к методу

Comment: Хм, действительно, код-то в вопросе я и не заметил. Mea culpa. Будем править ответ.